# How to simulate Amazon's 60 sec timeout on Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) on a local xAMP environment?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, timeout, amazon-elb

We are strugling with the infamous timeout of 60 seconds on ELB (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=33427).

Our PHP application fails on a few ajax requests.

We'd like to simulate ELB's behaviour on our development/test machines so that we don't have to wait for the deployment on EC2 to discover the bugs...

Does anyone know if there is a way to tune Apache so that it closes the HTTP queries like ELB does ?

NB: this timeout only affects queries that do not send anything for 60 seconds, it's not a max request time...!

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Amazon just added support for configuring timeouts: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/

Answer (score 0):

This timeout has to do with a request taking more than 60 seconds, without sending any data as a response. Long HTTP requests like this should really be avoided. Even browsers may give up if they dont receive any response within a timeout period.

If you can't get rid of long HTTP requests and you need to simulate it. You can use an fcgi/php-fpm configuration of php and provide a timeout of 60 seconds for which the fcgi process will wait for PHP to respond.